# OpenCV- Unable to access pixel value iof CV_8SC1

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat object of holding data of type `CV_8SC1` as I need to store negative values too.

```
cv::Mat layerMap;
layerMap = Mat(widgetSize.width(), widgetSize.height(), CV_8SC1);
layerMap = cv::Scalar::all(-1);
```

Now I want to access the value at particular row and column, so I write this-

```
int temp = layerMap.at<int>(canvasX, canvasY);
```

but this is faining an assertion-

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
(unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) ==
elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at
```

Both canvasX and canvasY are within the size bounds of layerMap as seen in debugger. I have previously used the same `at<int>(x,y)` method to access data in a cv_32S image.

Comment: Do you know the difference between matrices with type `CV_8SC1` and `CV_32S`?

Comment: Yeah, realized it after reading your comment- CV_8SC1 contains 8 bit pixels and should be accessed using `at<char>(x,y)` whereas CV_32S contains 32 bit large pixels which should be accessed using `at<int>(x,y)`.

@KeillRandor Post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a matrix of 8bit signed elements (`CV_8SC1`). In order to read them, use a `signed char` access:

```
schar temp = layerMap.at<schar>(canvasX, canvasY);
```

Comment: Since it is platform dependent whether char is signed or unsigned, wouldn't it be more correct to write `schar temp = layerMap.at<schar>(canvasX, canvasY);`? Otherwise someone may get a surprise when temp doesn't behave quite as expected.